# Counting probability question

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I have a pretty basic statistics problem on multinominal distribution. Any feedback would be appreciated.

If I have n marbles that can fall into three buckets (a, b, c) each with probability of $\eta_a$,  $\eta_b$,  $1-(\eta_a+\eta_b)$ . What is the probability of both buckets (a and b) to have at least one marble?

Thanks,

Further clarification: I would like to estimate the probability that both buckets (a and b) to have at least one marble each.

Comment: fixed the typo. thanks

Answer (score 2):

For convenience denote $\eta_c:=1-\eta_a-\eta_b$.

Let $A$ denote the event that bucket $a$ contains at least one marble and let $B$ denote the event that bucket $b$ contains at least one marble.

Then: $$P(A\cap B)=1-P(A^{\complement}\cup B^{\complement})=1-P(A^{\complement})-P(B^{\complement})+P(A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement})=$$$$1-(\eta_b+\eta_c)^n-(\eta_a+\eta_c)^n+\eta_c^n$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have added a further clarification in my question. I believe you result gives the probability of 1 marble being in either A or B. I would like to calculate that each buckets have at least 1 marble each.

Comment: My result answers your question. E.g. it gives $0$ as answer if $n=1$. That agrees with the probability that each buckets A,B have at least 1 marble in it, and agrees not with the probability of 1 marble in either A or B (that probability is positive). In my answer $P(A\cap B)$ is calculated, and not $P(A\cup B)$ (as you suggest).

Comment: thanks @drhab, could you please explain what A^C notation stands for?

Comment: It stands for the complement of $A$ so is in this context the event that bucket A will contain no marbles (or equivalently the event that all marbles end up in B or C).